# Detect static function called non-statically

Tags: php

How can one detect that a static function called non-statically?

For example, in this case:

```
class Foo
{
    public static function bar()
    {
        // How can I tell here that bar() is called on an instance?

        //var_dump(debug_backtrace()[0]['type'] == '::');
        // at all times the above prints bool(true)
        return 1;
    }
}

// later in the code
$foo = new Foo();
$foo::bar(); // that's fine

// even later
$foo->bar(); // this should not happen, yet it's here and there
```

I want to debug and eradicate cases such as on the last line above: someone somewhere wrongly calls a function on an instance, expecting that it would return something related to the instance in subject; instead one gets a somewhat related constant. Subsequently I need to know when this happens. If hell breaks loose or an exception gets thrown is fine with me too.

So far I've found that non-static calls for static functions are [internally translated into static calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15756165/93540), hence `debug_backtrace()[0]['type']` tells us nothing (it's `::` in both cases).

Comment: Calling a non-static function statically is an error. Calling a static function non-statically is **not**. Your code is example of the latter, not the former.

Comment: @Sherif I update the question to make it more obvious that that's really not error

Comment: I guess what I'm left wondering then, is why you care to detect this at all then if it's not an error? What threw me off is the fact that you use the statement "*debug these cases*", which leads me to believe that you are under the impression this can cause buggy behavior. It can't. PHP already knows at compile-time that the method is declared statically. So it doesn't care that you tried invoking the method from an object instance at runtime. It still knows to use a static context.

Comment: @Sherif it certainly causes a buggy behavior in a legacy code I'm trying to fix; how I'm supposed to fix it not knowing where's the trouble?

Comment: And what is this buggy behavior you're seeing? Chances are it has nothing to do with calling static methods non-statically, which is why I'm left wondering why you'd ask such a strange question. Perhaps try presenting the actual code that produces the problem and explain the desired behavior vs. the actual behavior of the real-world problem? Because right now the code you present in this question does not demonstrate any problems.

Comment: The bug is that someone somewhere calls this function on an instance, expecting that it would return something related to the instance in subject; instead one gets a somewhat related constant; I need to know when and where this happens; how I am supposed to know that?

Comment: Why should someone call a **static** method non-statically and expect a return related to the instance? I think it's clearly mentioned in the php manual that even if you call a static method non-statically that the call gets translated into a static context. The method will never run in a non-statically context. What you mention as a bug, is not a bug. It's a fundamental misunderstanding of PHP's static methods.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois exactly, and that's why I want to know when this happens; because it shouldn't be that way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to turn off `E_STRICT` for eternity, there's a way.

If the class `Foo` is, by sheer luck or providence, instantiated only in a couple of places like so:

```
public function getFoo()
{
    return new Foo();
}
```

Then if we subclass it and redefine `bar()`:

```
class Foo2 extends Foo
{
    public static function bar()
    {
         throw new Exception("You're calling Foo::bar() on an instance");
    }
}
```

Then if we replace `Foo` with `Foo2` where it were instantiated...

```
public function getFoo()
{
    //return new Foo();
    return new Foo2();
}
```

Exception will be thrown upon calling the above new static method:

```
$q = Foo::bar(); // no error just as before

$foo = $other->getFoo();
$foo->bar(); // throws exception
```

If anyone ever calls `$foo->bar();` on this kind-of-`Foo`, he would be quickly notified that he's making a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is twofold:

1. First one needs to disable `E_STRICT` reporting:

   ```
   error_reporting(error_reporting() ^ E_STRICT);
   ```
2. Next one should remove `static` keyword from the function's declaration.

   ```
   public /* static */ function bar()
   ```

Now it is possible to see if a function being called statically or dynamically with help of [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function:

```
class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
        $calledStatically = debug_backtrace()[0]['type'] == '::';

        if (!$calledStatically) {
            throw new Exception("Should not happen");
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

From the documentation:

> `type` (string): The current call type. If a method call, "->" is returned. If a static
>   method call, "::" is returned. If a function call, nothing is
>   returned.

Quick demo.

```
Foo::bar(); // normal result returned

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar(); // throws exception
```

Comment: As I note in the question, `debug_backtrace` isn't helping the way you believe it should.

Comment: ```$utils = new Utils();
$utils::whoDat();
$utils->whoDat();
``` How should this work?

Comment: Ok last update... not sure if removing "static" is a valid option.  But this seems to work.

Comment: Yup, it works if you disable [`E_STRICT` reporting for a while](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693946/non-static-method-should-not-be-called-statically)

Comment: Nope, go for it