# Yii 1.3 zii.widgets.grid.CGridView adding custom function to class

Tags: php, yii

I have functions for work with database in one of my controllers.
Something like this:

```
static function getCamByClassId($id)
{
    $connection=Yii::app()->db;
    $command=$connection->createCommand("some query");
    $camReader=$command->query();
    $camList=$command->queryAll();
    return $camList;
}
```

Also I'm using zii widget. Like this:

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'someId',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Image',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::image("/uploads/thumb_".$data->Lesson_ID."_".$data->Image, "" ,array(\'width\'=>195, \'height\'=>110))', 
        ,
        ),  
...
),));
```

Now I need to use other pictures there, that I get with help of this method.
I tried to replace `'value'` property on

```
'value' => 'CHtml::image(".$this->getCamByClassId($data->Lesson_ID)[0][\'Cam1\'].", "default image" ,array(\'width\'=>195, \'height\'=>110))',
```

And then I receive this exception:

```
Property "CDataColumn.getCamByClassId" is not defined.
```

There is no sense as I see to copy method into CDataColumn.php, because it looks for property and I can't set method return value to some property of this calss because it's result depends on `$id` parameter. How get I pass to 'value' property result of getCamByClassId?
**UPDATE**
Ok, I can use it like `LessonController::getCamByClassId`, but how can I pass `$data->LessonId` then?
**UPDATE1**
tried this

```
'value' => 'CHtml::image(".$this->grid->controller->getCamByClassId($data->Lesson_ID).", "default image" ,array(\'width\'=>195, \'height\'=>110))',
```

It says: Object of class CGridView could not be converted to string
**UPDATE2**
Checked last suggestion of topher

```
'value' => function($data, $row) {
    return CHtml::image(
        LessonController::getCamByClassId($data->Lesson_ID)[0]['Cam1'],
        "default image",
        array('width'=>195, 'height'=>110)
    );
}
```

My mistake: I had a typo. Now it says that 0 is undefined offset, gonna debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` in [`value`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#value-detail) refers to the [`CDataColumn`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn) instance and not your controller. Since your method is static and assuming your controller is autoloaded you can call the method using:

```
myController::getCamByClassId(...)
```

If not you can access it through `CDataColumn`'s [`grid`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#grid-detail) property which returns the [CGridView object](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) that has a [`controller`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget#controller-detail) property in turn:

```
$this->grid->controller->getCamByClassId(...)
```

For readability and easier maintenance, you can use an anonymous function instead:

```
'value' => function($data, $row) {
    return CHtml::image(
        LessonController::getCamByClassId($data->Lesson_ID)[0]['Cam1'],
        "default image",
        array('width'=>195, 'height'=>110)
    );
}
```

Comment: Ok, I can use myController::getCamByClassId(...) method. But then It says that $data->Lesson_ID id undefined variable, howeber it's defined and I use it.

Comment: I'll check your second variant.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It should be easier to debug.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow or today if I have time.

Answer (score 0):

you use $this->getCamByClassId but it is defined as static. So either remove the static attribute or use self::getCamByClassId.

Let us know if this works

Mark

Comment: `$this->myStaticMethod()` is [valid PHP code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15707148/428543). Whether it is good practice is another issue.